# how to return the last element of each row in C

Tags: c

This exercise asks me to fill the first row of the matrix then put the last element of each row in the first box of the next row and transfers the elements of the previous row to the next row like the following example:

5  7  9  2

2  5  7  9

9  2  5  7

7  9  2  5

5  7  9  2

The problem is start from the second row to the end in my code(the program does not return the last value of row 1 to the row 2) , can you help me

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main()
{
     int rows=5,cols=4;
     int T[rows][cols];
     int p=1;
     printf("The filling of this matrix :\n");
     for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
     {
          for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
          {
              if(i==0)
              {
                  scanf("%d",&T[i][j]);
              }
              T[p][0]=T[p-1][cols-1];
              for(int k=1;k<rows;k++)
              {
                  T[k][j+1]=T[k-1][j];
              }
           }
         p++;
     }

     printf("\nThe display of this matrix :\n");

     for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
     {printf("\n");
          for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
          {
               printf("[%d]",T[i][j]);
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, but "The problem is start from the second row to the end in my code" is not clear enough for me to understand your problem.

Comment: @Yunnosch the program does not return the last value of row 1 to the row 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){  

    int rows = 5, cols = 4;
    int T[rows][cols];
    printf("Filling the first row\n");

    for(int i=0; i < cols; i++){
        printf("Enter T[0][%d] = ",i)
        scanf("%d",&T[0][i]);
    }

    printf("Filling the rest matrix\n");
    for(i=1; i < rows; i++){
        for(j=0; j < cols; j++){
            if(j == 0){
                T[i][j] = T[i-1][cols-1];
            }
            else{
                T[i][j] = T[i-1][j-1];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("display the matrix\n");

    for(i=0 ; i < rows; i++){
        for(j=0 ; j < cols; j++){
            printf(" %d ",T[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n")
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, +1 for the correct answer, but please, note that providing the code without an explanation doesn't help OP

Comment: Thank you for your advice @DavidRanieri. I'll take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing outside of the bounds of the array here:

```
T[k][j+1]=T[k-1][j]; // j + 1 = 4 in the last iteration in a range [0 ... 3]
```

You are over-complicating things, you don't need an extra loop (`k`) nor an extra variable (`p`), all the information needed is already in the inner loop, just check the position of `i` and `j`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int rows = 5, cols = 4; 
    int T[rows][cols];  // Notice that this is a VLA, avoid using
                        // them and use enum {rows = 5, cols = 4}
                        // when values are known before hand

    printf("The filling of this matrix :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                scanf("%d", &T[i][j]);
            }
            else
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    T[i][j] = T[i - 1][cols -1];
                }
                else
                {
                    T[i][j] = T[i - 1][j - 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe display of this matrix :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            printf("[%d]", T[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

You can simplify:

```
            if (j == 0)
            {
                T[i][j] = T[i - 1][cols -1];
            }
            else
            {
                T[i][j] = T[i - 1][j - 1];
            }
```

using a ternary operator:

```
            T[i][j] = T[i - 1][(j == 0) ? cols - 1 : j - 1];
```